# How to add a section in shopify footer?

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I am using the taste theme on shopify and I would like to add a section (collapsible-contact.liquid) in my footer. I have found this discussion https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/nested-sections/m-p/424873, but Im not sure how to do it.

So my request is to add the collapsible content in the footer but only for mobile.

Here is a picture of what i would like:

[image: Collapsible accordion in the footer]

Comment: Can you provide more details? Your link is also archived, so we can't see what you're talking about. What have you tried so far? Any code changes? How does your Theme Editor look like (like what have you changed?)?